# 'Hazelcast is not active' exception thrown when sending a task to a node that is shutting down

Tags: hazelcast

Hazelcast 4.2.6, 2-node cluster (S1 and S2). I have an IMap where the key has two attributes (rateId + methodId), using 'methodId' as a 'PartitionKey'.

Let's suppose the key = [ 5, 36 ] belongs to S1. When a request arrives to S1 using this key, a set of operations are executed locally following the pattern 'lock+get+put+unlock'.
When a request arrives to S2, we are sending a Callable to the owner of the key (which is S1, using the 'methodId'), and again the previous pattern is executed locally and the result is returned to S2.

If now I shutdown S2 (which is not the owner of the key) everything goes well. Then I start it again and now I shutdown S1 (which is still the owner of the key), then the logs on the S2 node show the following error for many requests:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
        at com.ventusproxy.proxy.services.rates.ExecuteRateCallback.onFailure(ExecuteRateCallback.java:35)
        at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.ExecutionCallbackAdapter.accept(ExecutionCallbackAdapter.java:40)
        at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.ExecutionCallbackAdapter.accept(ExecutionCallbackAdapter.java:27)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$WhenCompleteNode.lambda$execute$0(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:1563)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
        at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.DistributedExecutorService$Processor.run(DistributedExecutorService.java:278)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:887)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
Caused by: com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractDistributedObject.throwNotActiveException(AbstractDistributedObject.java:115)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractDistributedObject.lifecycleCheck(AbstractDistributedObject.java:110)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractDistributedObject.getNodeEngine(AbstractDistributedObject.java:104)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.lock(MapProxyImpl.java:320)
        at com.ventusproxy.proxy.services.rates.store.ClusterStore.lock(ClusterStore.java:18)
        at com.ventusproxy.proxy.services.rates.Rate.executeCuota(Rate.java:113)
        at com.ventusproxy.proxy.services.rates.RateManager.applyQuotas(RateManager.java:85)
        at com.ventusproxy.proxy.services.rates.ExecuteRateTask.call(ExecuteRateTask.java:46)
        at com.ventusproxy.proxy.services.rates.ExecuteRateTask.call(ExecuteRateTask.java:18)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.DistributedExecutorService$Processor.run(DistributedExecutorService.java:276)
        ... 6 more
```

The 'ExecuteRateTask' is the task sent to S1 that tries to acquire the lock on the imap at 'ClusterStore.java:18'. There the exception 'Hazelcast instance is not active' is thrown and the 'ExecuteRateCallback.onFailure' is invoked.

What it seems here is:

1. Hazelcast instance is stopping on S1 (calling 'this.hz.shutdown()').
2. S2 still sees the S1 member and the callable is sent to S1.
3. S1 receives the callable but when it tries to use the IMap throws the exception 'Hazelcast instance is not active'

Is this what is happening? If so, is there any way to avoid this exception? Or, for each task sent to another node, must I control if 'hz' is still active on that node before proceeding to execute the task?

Thanks,
Joan.